# why int.TryParse cannot initialise multiple variables

Tags: c#, .net

I am using `int.TryParse` to parse to variables (saved as strings in the database) and am curious why I cannot initialise 2 variables:

```
int min, 
    max;
```

using the following conditional statement:

```
bool lengthCompatible = int.TryParse(string1, out min) &&
                        int.TryParse(string2, out max);
```

Visual Studio (2015) produces the following code highlighting:

> Use of unassigned local variable 'max'
>
> Local variable 'max' might not be initialized before accessing

However, if I use 2 conditional statements:

```
bool minParse = int.TryParse(sentenceType.MinimumLength, out min);
bool maxParse = int.TryParse(sentenceType.MaximumLength, out max);
```

I can compile with no errors.

Curiouser and curiouser! Any insight appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: because min may fail, max wont even be started

Comment: The && operator uses short-circuit evaluation.  So the second TryParse call might not execute and max will not have a value.  Use the & operator instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well you're using `&&`, which is short-circuiting... if `int.TryParse(string1, out min)` returns `false`, the second call to `int.TryParse` won't be made, so `max` isn't definitely assigned.

You *could* write:

```
if (int.TryParse(string1, out min) &&
    int.TryParse(string2, out max))
{
    // Use min and max here
}
```

... because then the compiler knows that you only reach the body of the `if` statement if both calls have been executed.

Alternatively you could use the non-short-circuiting version with `&` instead of `&&`:

```
bool lengthCompatible = int.TryParse(string1, out min) &
                        int.TryParse(string2, out max);
```

That's slightly unusual though. The advantage of the `if` version above is that you'll retain the performance benefit of `&&`, in that you won't bother trying to parse `string2` if you don't need to. (It depends on exactly what you're trying to do, of course.)

Answer (score 1):

Because if the first `int.TryParse(string1, out min)` returns false, the second `int.TryParse(string2, out max)` will not be executed due to boolean short-circuiting.

In that case, `max` will not have been initialised.

You could just initialise `max` and `min` to zero:

```
int min = 0,
    max = 0;

...

bool lengthCompatible = int.TryParse(string1, out min) && int.TryParse(string2, out max);
```

Or only use the `max` and `min` after checking the result of the `&&` as per other answers.

Answer (score 0):

This is called shortcut boolean evaluation. This makes sure that boolean expressions are only evaluated until the final result is found.

If the first `int.TryParse(string1, out min)` already, the second one will not be executed, as the overall result will already be `false`. So the `max` variable is not guaranteed to be always initialized.